# Does a logical right shift ever add a 1 in Java?

Tags: java, bit-shift

I have a paper that has `1111 1111 1111 xxxx` as the answer to `(short)(Z>>>12)`. The program given to us to check our bit operation answers also gives this answer to a (`short`) input. From my understanding, only the arithmetic shift (`>>`) is sign sensitive.

Edit:

```
Z = -2009  (or 1111100000100111 in binary)

(short)(Z>>>12) = -1 (or 1111111111111111 in binary)
```

Comment: it depends on your value of Z

Comment: What do you mean by adding 1? Provide an example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the problem, it may be a trick question.

Here is one such program that outputs the given result:

```
short z = (short)0b1111_1000_0010_0111;  // -2009
System.out.println( (short)(z >>> 12) ); // prints -1
```

This happens because *before* the right-shift, the `short` gets promoted to `int` by way of sign extension. This fills the 16 bits *above* the range of short with 1s.

So to put it another way:

```
// as a short
                    1111_1000_0010_0111
// sign extended to int
1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1000_0010_0111
// shifted right 12
0000_0000_0000_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111
// cast back to short
                    1111_1111_1111_1111
```

If you don't want the sign extension, you have to mask:

```
System.out.println( (short)((z & 0xffff) >>> 12) );
```

Mathematical operators in Java do not ever operate on `char`, `byte` and `short`, they always get implicitly promoted to `int` first.

Comment: This explained it, thanks! That was a little tricky and requires you to know that java promotes short to int. I had to shift 17 times or mask to see 0's.